# Preparing Rules Based List for Promotions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to put together a promotions list based on  a set of rules

1. In table #productdetail I need to pick up items that have available =1 or available =2 and expected <=08052019 and not_sellable =0
2. From #product table I need to join id with pid in #productdetail and coalesce (vendor_id to get the vendor_id
3. Using the vendor_id that I have got from the step above i need to get the vendorname from #vendor table..
4. From the #Asin table I need to select the latest lastconfirmedasin from the list of items selected in step 1 and also ensure that I should not pick up data from rows where disable =1
5. From the #pageviews table I need to get the number of pageviews perday for every item based on the lastconfirmedasin for the list of items selected in step 1

Here for every item if I have datetype =day and also datetype =month then I need to select data from datetype =day and select sum(pageviews)/count of days to get the sum of pageviews per day

Also if I have only datetype =month then I need to select (sum(pageviews)(count of rows that have month)/30

6. Then in the promo table I need to select the average promo% got for the items selected in step 1..The average promo% is calculated as avg((pre_promo_price-promo_price)/promo_price*100))...This will be calculated at the vendor level...So if the vendor has 3 items then the average promo% is calculated as avg([avg((pre_promo_price-promo_price)/promo_price*100)
7. Then the cost is taken based on if in the table #promo has the date in between or included in promo_start and promo_end (for example today's date being 08/16/2019 is included then the pre promo cost is to taken as the cost for that item otherwise the cost from #product_detail table should be taken
8. Then I am calculating the priority of the items by vendor(meaning within each vendor ) prioritizing the items based on the power(calculated as pageviewsperday*price)-Higher value of an item within a vendor gets the first priority

The tables:

```
create table #productdetail
(
itemid int,
available int,
expected date,
isnotsellable int,
pid int,
vendor_id varchar(50),
cost float,
price float)

insert  into #productdetail values
('123','1',NULL,'1','1','201','180','200'),
('125','2','08/05/2019','0','1','NULL','40','60'),
('127','1',NULL,'0','1','201','60','80'),
('129','2',NULL,'0','2','203','80','100'),
('131','1',NULL,'0','2','203','70','90'),
('133','1',NULL,'1','2','203','90','110'),
('135','1',NULL,'0','7','206','110','130'),
('137','1',NULL,'0','8','207','120','140'),
('139','1',NULL,'0','8','207','30','50'),
('141','1',NULL,'0','8','207','40','60'),
('143','1',NULL,'0','11','210','60','80'),
('145','1',NULL,'0','11','210','70','90'),
('147','1',NULL,'1','11','210','50','70'),
('149','1',NULL,'0','11','210','20','40'),
('151','1',NULL,'0','15','211','30','50'),
('153','1',NULL,'0','16','NULL','40','60'),
('155','2','08/29/2019','1','15','211','60','80'),
('157','2','08/04/2019','1','18','216','30','50'),
('159','2','08/06/2019','0','19','217','20','40'),
('161','2','08/03/2019','0','20','218','60','80'),
('163','2','08/15/2019','0','21','NULL','90','110')

create table #product
(id int,
vendor_id varchar(50)
)

insert into #product values
('1','201'),
('1','201'),
('1','201'),
('2','203'),
('2','203'),
('2','203'),
('7','NULL'),
('8','207'),
('8','207'),
('8','207'),
('11','210'),
('11','210'),
('11','210'),
('11','210'),
('15','211'),
('15','211'),
('15','211'),
('16','206'),
('18','216'),
('19','NULL'),
('20','218'),
('21','219')

create table #vendor
(vendor_id varchar(50),
vendorname varchar(50)
)

insert into #vendor values
('201','cola'),
('203','foam'),
('207','fill'),
('210','falon'),
('211','chiran'),
('216','Hummer'),
('218','sulps'),
('219','culp'),
('217','jko'),
('206','JINCO')

create table #asin
(disable int,
item_id int,
lastconfirmed datetime2,
lastconfirmedasin varchar(50)
)

insert into #asin values
('0','123','12/19/18 10:19 PM','iopyu'),
('1','123','12/19/16 10:19 PM','hjyug'),
('1','125','5/19/19 10:19 PM','uirty'),
('0','125','12/19/16 10:19 PM','1yuio'),
('0','127','2/19/19 10:19 PM','klbnm'),
('1','127','12/19/18 10:19 PM','lopgh'),
('0','127','12/19/16 10:19 PM','nmbh'),
('0','129','11/19/16 10:19 PM','jklh'),
('0','131','11/19/19 10:19 PM','werat'),
('1','133','6/19/19 10:19 PM','vbnwe'),
('0','133','1/19/19 10:19 PM','mnwer'),
('0','133','11/19/17 10:19 PM','sdert'),
('0','135','6/19/19 10:19 PM','vbsdx'),
('0','137','6/19/17 10:19 PM','bnxct')

create table #pageviews
(startdate date,
lastconfirmedasin varchar(50),
noofpageviews int,
datetype varchar(20))

insert into #pageviews values
('05/08/2017','hjyug','102','day'),
('09/05/2017','hjyug','201','day'),
('10/05/2019','hjyug','1002','day'),
('09/05/2018','iopyu','345','month'),
('10/06/2018','iopyu','545','month'),
('06/05/2019','1yuio','300','day'),
('06/06/2019','1yuio','200','day'),
('09/04/2019','uirty','150','day'),
('11/4/2019','uirty','200','day'),
('12/4/2019','nmbh','300','day'),
('04/15/2019','lopgh','400','day'),
('04/15/2019','klbnm','500','day'),
('04/16/2019','klbnm','1000','day'),
('04/15/2019','jklh','600','day'),
('04/15/2019','werat','700','day'),
('04/15/2019','sdert','800','day'),
('04/15/2019','mnwer','900','day'),
('04/15/2019','vbnwe','1000','day'),
('04/15/2019','vbsdx','1100','day'),
('04/25/2019','vbsdx','3000','day'),
('04/15/2019','bnxct','1200','month'),
('05/31/2019','bnxct','2200','month'),
('04/16/2019','bnxct','90','day'),
('04/17/2019','bnxct','100','day'),
('04/18/2019','bnxct','120','day')

create table #promo
(itemid int,
promo_cost float,
pre_promo_cost float,
promo_start varchar(50),
promo_end varchar(50))

insert into #promo values 
('123','214.7','220','10/08/2019','22/08/2019'),
('123','225','230','01/02/2018','15/02/2018'),
('125','400','430','12/08/2019','19/08/2019'),
('125','380','390','15/02/2019','30/02/2019'),
('127','120','140','15/03/2019','30/03/2019'),
('129','80','100','15/04/2019','30/04/2019'),
('129','110','120','01/04/2019','10/04/2019'),
('131','80','100','01/02/2019','15/02/2019'),
('131','110','120','10/01/2019','15/01/2019'),
('133','230','420','10/01/2019','15/01/2019'),
('135','250','440','10/01/2019','15/01/2019'),
('137','270','460','10/01/2019','15/01/2019'),
('139','290','480','10/01/2019','15/01/2019'),
('141','310','500','10/01/2019','15/01/2019'),
('143','330','520','10/01/2019','15/01/2019'),
('145','350','540','10/08/2019','22/08/2019')

create table #output
(itemid int,
available int,
expected date,
isnotsellable int,
pid int,
vendor_id varchar(50),
vendorname varchar(50),
lastconfirmedasin varchar(50),
pageviewsperday int,
promoavg float,
cost float,
price float,
[power] int,
[priority] int)

insert into #output values 
('151','1',NULL,'0','15','211','chiran','','0','0','30','50','0','1'),
    ('127','1',NULL,'0','1','201','cola','klbnm','750','6.3','60','80','60000','1'),
('125','2','08/05/2019','0','1','201','cola','','0','0','430','60','0','2'),
('143','1',NULL,'0','11','210','falon','','0','0','60','80','0','1'),
('145','1',NULL,'0','11','210','falon','','0','0','540','90','0','2'),
('149','1',NULL,'0','11','210','falon','','0','0','20','40','0','3'),
('137','1',NULL,'0','8','207','fill','bnxct','103','65.73','120','140','14420','1'),
('139','1',NULL,'0','8','207','fill','','0','0','30','50','0','2'),
('141','1',NULL,'0','8','207','fill','','0','0','40','60','0','3'),
('131','1',NULL,'0','2','203','foam','werat','700','30.16','70','90','63000','1'),
('135','1',NULL,'0','7','206','JINCO','vbsdx','2050','76','110','130','266500','1'),
('153','1',NULL,'0','16','206','JINCO','','0','0','40','60','0','2'),
('161','2','08/03/2019','0','20','218','sulps','','0','0','60','80','0','1')
```

Code tried:

```
; WITH firstsel AS (
    SELECT itemid, available, expected, isnotsellable, pid, vendor_id
    FROM   #productdetail
    WHERE  available = 1
      AND  isnotsellable = 0
   UNION ALL
    SELECT itemid, available, expected, isnotsellable, pid, vendor_id
    FROM   #productdetail
    WHERE  available = 2
      AND  isnotsellable = 0
      AND  expected <= '20190805'
), addvendorid AS (
   SELECT fs.itemid, fs.available, fs.expected, fs.pid, fs.isnotsellable,  
          coalesce(fs.vendor_id, p.vendor_id) AS vendor_id
   FROM   firstsel fs
   JOIN   #product p ON fs.pid = p.id
), asinnumbered AS (
   SELECT item_id, lastconfirmedasin, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY lastconfirmedasin DESC) AS rowno
   FROM   #asin
)
SELECT av.itemid, av.available, av.expected, av.isnotsellable, av.pid, 
       av.vendor_id, v.vendorname, an.lastconfirmedasin, 
       isnull(pv.pageviews, 0) AS pageviews, isnull(p.promoavg, 0) AS promoavg
FROM   addvendorid av
JOIN   #vendor v ON av.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
LEFT  JOIN  (asinnumbered an 
             JOIN (SELECT lastconfirmedasin, SUM(pageviews) AS pageviews
                   FROM   #pageviews
                   GROUP  BY lastconfirmedasin) AS pv ON an.lastconfirmedasin = pv.lastconfirmedasin)
       ON an.item_id = av.itemid
      AND an.rowno  = 1
LEFT  JOIN  (SELECT itemid, avg((pre_promo_price-promo_price)/promo_price*100) AS promoavg
             FROM   #promo
             GROUP  BY itemid) AS p ON p.itemid = av.itemid
ORDER BY av.itemid
```

Comment: Am I missing something here, or have you not asked a question? You've set out a bunch of steps, great, but what is the problem you're facing? What is it you need help with?

Comment: @larnu: I am trying to get the #output table as the result based on the bunch of the steps...

Comment: @Larnu: Yes I have few pieces of the process that I want help with..Yes I will post my code that I have and also the few steps that I need help with and the error

Comment: My code is too long to share in comment

Comment: It shouldn't be in the comments anyway; it should be part of your question..

Comment: duplicate on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/144bb338-9939-4924-b0ac-5adeeaa78037/preparing-rules-based-list-for-promotions?forum=transactsql). The forums are not free code-writing services. In addition, this is far too broad for SO. Suggest you start writing code in steps - dividing the work into achievable goals and implementing and verifying as you reach each one.

Comment: @Larnu: I have posted the code that I have tried too...